# Отсутствие однозначных норм в ударениях

Tags: фонетика

Почему грамматически правильно писать "профессорА", но "бухгАлтеры"?
Есть ли правила, регламентирующие эти окончания?
Если нет, то кто сказал, что правильно именно так.
Ну напишу я бухгалтерА, а мне зачтут за ошибку. Тогда пусть объяснят, что правильно так, а не иначе. Или кто-то из отдела образования скажет:"Я хочу ставить ударение так". 
инспекторА, но инженЕры; РедАкторы и редакторА и так и сяк правильно. Где нормы? Это русский язык или черт знает что

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Трудные формы множественного числа имен существительных ("Грамота.ру",http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=plural)
"В современном русском литературном языке варианты, колеблющиеся в форме им. п. мн. ч., насчитывают свыше 300 слов. Очагом распространения флексии -а (-я) являются сферы просторечия и профессионального языка. В связи с этим формы на -а, (-я) имеют часто разговорную или профессиональную окраску: договора, слесаря, токаря. Формы же на -ы (-и) более нейтральны и для большинства слов отвечают традиционным нормам литературного языка. Однако в некоторых случаях формы на -а, (-я) уже вытеснили формы на -ы (-и).

Кроме этого, можно запомнить ряд закономерностей, облегчающих выбор флексии (окончания) именительного падежа множественного числа:

Склоняемые существительные среднего рода, начальная форма которых оканчивается на -КО, имеют безударную флексию мн. ч. им. п. -и (личики, перышки, яблоки, брюхи). Исключение составляют существительные с ударными окончаниями мн. ч.: войска и облака.

Остальные существительные среднего рода в форме мн. ч. принимают окончание -а (-я): болота, поля, моря, окна.

Форма на -а, -я у некоторых слов может быть единственной или преобладающей: бок - бока (боки только во фразеологическом сочетании руки в боки); век - века (веки только во фразеологических сочетаниях в кои-то веки, на веки вечные, во веки веков), глаз - глаза, луг - луга, мех - меха, снег - снега, стог - стога,  шелк - шелка.

Формы могут иметь разное значение: тона (о цвете) и тоны (о звуке), хлеба (о злаках) и хлебы (о печеном хлебе), цеха и цехи (на предприятии) и цехи (средневековые организации ремесленников).

Формы существительных могут различаться по стилистической окраске: борта и устар. борты; дома и устар. домы; корма и устар. кормы; рога и устар. и поэт. роги; сорта и устар. сорты; тома и устар. томы, а также громы и поэт. грома; гробы и поэт. гроба.

Наконец, формы существительных могут быть равноправными и взаимозаменяемыми: года и годы (но: годы юности, тяжелых лишений; девяностые, нулевые годы), цеха и цехи (на предприятии), шторма и штормы.

Чтобы решить вопрос о статусе "спорной" формы слова (ненормативная, вариантная, стилистически окрашенная и др.), в любом случае нужно обратиться к словарю.

Нестандартно множественное число образуется у слов ребенок - дети, человек - люди, дно - донья и некоторых других".

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не понял. Каждый раз экспертизу назначать по написанию ? Единых правил нет  ?
Велик и могуч....

Comment: Да, каждый раз экспертизу. Сначала - внутреннюю. Потом - к словарю. Не помогло - к специалистам... Вас смущает, что в словаре русского языка ~70000 слов? Ну, что поделать. Такой уж у нас язык.

Comment: <Формы существительных могут различаться по стилистической окраске: борта и устар. борты; дома и устар. домы; корма и устар. кормы; рога и устар. и поэт. роги; сорта и устар. сорты; тома и устар. томы, а также громы и поэт. грома; гробы и поэт. гроба.

**сватЫ** и устар. **свАты**

Answer (score 0):

Напомнили ;)

Перефразируя предположение хулиганствующего лингвиста А.М. Григоренко (в кн. "Великий и могучий"), авторизированное издание таблицы умножения выглядело бы приблизительно так:

"**3×3:** Мы склоняемся к тому, что "**3×3 = 11**" (А.А. Зализняк). М.Ф. Фасмер, полагающий, что "**3×3 = 8**", не прав, а позиция В.М. Живова ("**3×3 = 12**") неубедительна."

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, лучше обратиться к словарю. .
А ещё можно выучить такой стишочек:

Выполняя договоры,
Инженеры и шофёры, 
Столяры и маляры
Потрудились все на славу, 
Чтоб за месяц до зимы
Возвести домов кварталы
Для народа, для страны.